# Log to a different file depending on a contains substring when filter

Tags: nlog

I would like to setup filters in my nlog.config in such a way that a log entry should go to one file (defined by the file target `domainTarget`) if a message contains a substring and to another file (defined by the file target `technicalTarget`) if it does not.

Put in another way: Whatever is included in `domainTarget` (no matter how complex its rules are) should never show up in `technicalTarget`.

This is what I tried:

```xml
<rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="domainTarget">
        <filters>
            <when condition="contains('${message}', 'mysubstring')" action="LogFinal"/>
        </filters>
    </logger>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="technicalTarget"/>
</rules>
```

With these settings it logs **everything** to `domainTarget`. And also logs everything to `technicalTarget` **except** messages with the substring.

Can someone

1. Explain the algorithm how those filters are applied.
2. Show me the right filter settings to achieve my above goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried to use [defaultAction](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Filtering-log-messages) introduced with NLog 4.6?

```xml
<logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="domainTarget">
  <filters defaultAction="Ignore">
    <when condition="contains('${message}', 'mysubstring')" action="LogFinal" />
  </filters>
</logger> 
<logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="technicalTarget"/>
```

Comment: That works, even though it does not validate against the xsd (`xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"`) which I got from the NLog.Schema.4.6.3.nupkg I still don't quite understand how all those `action`s and `defaultAction` and the `final="true"` play together, I have to say that XML-based config DSL is all but intuitive.

Comment: @bitbonk Logger-rules (with final=true) are usually easy to understand for most (Final stops logevent from reaching logger-rules below). Filters on the other hand are more difficult to use, but defaultAction makes it a little easier.

Comment: @bitbonk Maybe an interesting read: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4051307/NLog-Rules-and-filters

Comment: The xsd warning is fixed in NLog 4.6.4

Comment: @bitbonk about the questions in your comment: the defaultAction is log (will be changed in NLog 5), the final=true is so the logs aren't written to technicalTarget - otherwise you need the same filters. Hope this makes things clear, otherwise feel free to edit the wiki ;)